# Aligning two imageviews properly in custom toolbar - android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-toolbar

I want to display two ImageViews  using my custom  toolbar.
This is the XML for my custom toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_backbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cr_logo1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_sos2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/sos_button_copy"

                android:gravity="end"
   />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I want the first ImageView in the center (which it is coming correctly), and the second ImageView to the right.

Using the above XML displays the first ImageView but not second.
If I use the second ImageView before the first, the second ImageView appears towards the left,and the first one towards the right, which is not what I want.

How do I write XML such that the first ImageView (@+id/tool_bar_backbutton) appears in center, and the second ImageView (@+id/action_sos2) appears at the right?

Comment: Try changing the <LinearLayout> to <RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

> Change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and also remove spacing from left side of `Toolbar` by `contentInset`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_backbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_sos2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:gravity="end"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_eye" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar_backbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/cr_logo1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action_sos2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sos_button_copy"

  />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding_top="5dp"
            android:padding_bottom="5dp"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/sos_button_copy"
                android:visibility="invisible"

                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tool_bar_backbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/cr_logo1"
                />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/action_sos2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/sos_button_copy"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```